# What is the difference between the following array declarations in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm building a menu in my WinForm app and i was doing something like :

```
MenuItem[] items = new MenuItem[] { };
```

And after :

```
for (int namesIndex = 0; namesIndex < menuNames.Length; namesIndex++)
{
    MenuItem item = new MenuItem(menuNames[namesIndex]);

    for (int entriesIndex = 0; entriesIndex < menuEntries.GetLength(1); entriesIndex++)
    {
       item.MenuItems.Add(menuEntries[namesIndex, entriesIndex]);
    }

    items[namesIndex] = item;
}
```

And an IndeOutOfRangeException is thrown :

[image]

After this annoying exception i modified the array declaration with this :

```
 MenuItem[] items = new MenuItem[] { null };
```

and everything works like a charm.

And now the question : **Does anyone out there knows why the above array declaration works, and the other doesn't?**
Thanks alot

Comment: Given you don't know how many there are going to be, why don't you use say List<MenuItem>?

Comment: I don't want to use Lists(it may sound goofy but here it goes) lately i've been using to much lists and dictionaries and lambdas and etc... with this one i'm going classic (told you it sounds strange):D

Comment: That's a good reason to use them, you run into wee problems like this and learn what us folk had to do in the bad ole days. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using array initializers to construct the array, so the length of the array will be given by the data you provide.

The first example declares an array with a length of zero as you don't provide any elements. I.e. it cannot contain any elements.

The second example declares an array of length one.

Answer (score 2):

```
MenuItem[] items = new MenuItem[] { };
```

This creates an array with 0 items in it.

```
MenuItem[] items = new MenuItem[] { null };
```

This creates an array with 1 item in it (it's null, but that still counts).

You probably want to initialize for the number of items you want (`new MenuItem[menuNames.Length]`, for example). Or use `new List<MenuItem>()` instead, and call `Add()`.

Answer (score 2):

"Everything works like a charm" only to the extent that `menuNames` has exactly one item. You need to change the code as follows to make it work:

```
MenuItem[] items = new MenuItem[menuNames.Length];
```

The reason you saw a crash in the first case is that you created an array with zero items, while in the second case you created an array with one item. If `menuNames` has more than one element, your code would start crashing again.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop iterates over compares the loop variable to `menuNames.Length`, while your using the indexer of the `items` array.  One of the two is wrong.

Additionally, if you want to be adding additional items to a collection, then you should almost certainly be using a `List`, not an array.